# Angular Typescript : Using an Object as an attribute of another Object before its definition

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

i'm implementing **"parents-childs"** relations between several objects derived from the same class.

**My class (model) is the following  :**

```
export class Node {
  public name: string;
  public isLocked: boolean;
  public canBeUnlocked: boolean;
  public parentNodes: Node[];
  public childNodes: Node[];
}
```

Under my component i'm declaring several objects derived from this model , but some objects are using objects before their plain declaration:

**Test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Node} from '../models/node.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mage',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  NodesList= [];
  Node1: any;
  Node2: any;
  Node3: any;
  Node4: any;
  Node5: any;
  Node6: any;

  constructor() {
    this.Node1 = new Node('Node1', false, true , null, [this.Node2]);
    this.Node2 = new Node('Node2', true, true, [this.Node1], [this.Node3 , this.Node4]);
    this.Node3 = new Node('Node3', true, false , [this.Node2], [this.Node5]);
    this.Node4 = new Node('Node4', true, false , [this.Node2], [this.Node6]);
    this.Node5 = new Node('Node5', true, false , [this.Node3], null);
    this.Node6 = new Node('Node6', true, false , [this.Node4], null);
    // The list
    this.NodesList = [this.Node1, this.Node2, this.Node3 , this.Node4 , this.Node5 , this.Node6];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.Node2);
    console.log(this.NodesList);
  }
}
```

The problem , is with the **"child nodes"** ,

***for example*** for the *Node1* : *Node2* is a child node , but it's get "undefined" when calling `console.log(Node1)` , maybe because i'm calling *Node2* as an attribute for the *Node1* , before defining *Node2* itself .

THe problem is occuring similarly with the other nodes.

Any idea to deal with that ??
**Suggestions ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just undefined, impossible to console.log value of undefined object. Solution depends on your goals.

For example, you can:

```
  public parentNodes?: Node[];
  public childNodes?: Node[];
}
```

This will allow create object without child nodes, so console.log will output your objet, just without some properties that hasn't been initialed.

Or:

```
<div> {{ Node2.childNodes?[0] }}  </div>
```

this will show first childNode in HTML if node has it.

You could also add missing childNodes in some other Angular's lifeCycleHook:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.Node2.childNodes = [this.Node1, this.Node3];
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.Node2);
  console.log(this.NodesList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already found the problem: you are using the variables before assigning a value to them. Take for example these two lines:

```
this.Node4 = new Node('Node4', true, false , [this.Node2], [this.Node6]);
...
this.Node6 = new Node('Node6', true, false , [this.Node4], null);
```

`this.Node4` tries to use `this.Node6` before assigning a value to `this.Node6`. And you cannot exchange these lines because then `this.Node6` would be using `this.Node4` before a value is assigned.

The solution is to assign first the right values to the variables, and later specifying the relationships between them, like this:

```
this.Node4 = new Node('Node4', true, false);
...
this.Node6 = new Node('Node6', true, false);
..
this.Node4.parentNodes = [this.Node2];
this.Node4.childNodes = [this.Node6];
...
this.Node6.parentNodes = [this.Node4];
```